# Optocoupler can't handle surge in collector current

Tags: power-supply, opto-isolator

Consider the following application where a control board talks to a CO2 sensor ([PASCO2](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-PASCO2V01-DataSheet-v01_03-DataSheet-v01_03-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c80027ecd01809278f1af1ba2)) living on its own PCB and connected to the control board through a wired terminal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f55jMu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This system works like a charm but we need to reduce the overall consumption because we would like to make this system work off-grid with a large battery that will be replaced every other day.

The main source of power consumption is the CO2 sensor board which consumes ~22mA of current all the time, of which 20mA originate from the 12V line alone and the steady consumption from the DC/DC converter on the CO2 board ([datasheet here](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3118403.pdf)).
We would like to implement a switching mechanism on that 12V line to the sensor board, as depicted on the following updated schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fealJp.png)</sup>

With the introduction of the optocoupler (a [CNY17-3](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/39399.pdf)), the collector current of the optocoupler `Ic` is around 20mA most of the time and the forward current `If` is around 60mA.

When a measurement from the sensor is triggered by the µC, leading to a temporary surge in current consumption (`Ic` ≃ 40mA), the optocoupler only drives the higher current for a fraction of seconds, thus less time than without the optocoupler.

As a result, we get erroneous values of the CO2 concentration compared to the system depicted in the first circuit (without optocoupler).

It is also worth noting that problem happens even if `SENSOR_EN` is HIGH all the time (i.e. optocoupler driving all the time), meaning the the problem does not come from the switching time of the optocoupler but rather from something else solely related to the output stage.

How could we explain the origin of this transient problem and could we solve it?

Comment: Could you post the datasheet for the sensor and the DC/DC converter `U6`?

Comment: Why (ab)use an opto as power switch? The conventional way would be a MOSFET. Even a small signal FET should be enough here.

Comment: Are there any ramifications of switching the CO2 sensor?  Like, does it have a "warm-up period", or does accuracy change or stabilize after some amount of time?

Comment: `...and the forward current If is around 60mA.` You are driving the opto's LED directly from the MCU **O.o** Have you broken it yet?

Comment: @RohatKılıç you are right, I'm currently exceeding the max. 40mA rating of the GPIO but I could go down to 40mA since If is not the limiting factor here (with the CTR of the optocoupler, If=40mA would be more than enough to drive Ic=40mA). I was just increasing If to make sure that was not to problem, you may consider that I've updated R1 so that we don't exceed the max. current rating from the µC GPIO.

Comment: @rdtsc there is indeed some warm-up period to take into account but the tests have been performed after enough time to dismiss it as the source of the problem.

Comment: @tobalt I tried to use a MOSFET as a switch in a previous design but ran into problems because I was trying to switch the whole sensor board on the GND side because I wanted to switch off both the 3.3V and 12V line at the same time (don't judge me, I have come to learn it was bad idea :-)). I decided to give a try to an optocoupler instead of using a MOSFET on the VCC side but I might be wrong. If you really think a MOSFET would do the trick, what circuit would you recommend?

Comment: @awjlogan datasheets links added in the question.

Comment: @RohatKılıç to elaborate a bit more on the If=60mA not burning the GPIO, I ran the tests above by driving the opto from the 3.3V line directly (not through the GPIO), so that's probably the reason why the µC didn't explode.

Comment: Research "high side switch"; many options are possible.

Comment: Looks like the sensor controlled through IIC interface. Check the sensor datasheet, it may have the sleep command.

Comment: Have you considered a regulator with an enable pin? Wait, U3 isn't a regulator at all, it's an *isolator*! Just switch its ground terminal then, problem solved. You can also reduce cost of this part by using a boost converter, since everything seems to be common-ground.

Comment: @TimWilliams nice idea but that would require both an additional wire in the connector and some adjustments to the sensor board to use this new enable signal, sadly I can't really touch the sensor board for backward compatibility reasons...

Comment: @user263983 Yes but even putting the sensor IC to sleep won't prevent the DC/DC regulator from driving current from the 12V line, so the 20mA will remain.

Comment: @Buddyshot An extra wire in the connector to switch U3 or substitute it with an enableable regulator??

Comment: @TimWilliams wait I didn't read you well, thought you were talking about U6. Turning off the whole TBA2-0512 is actually...the simplest, easiest solution. Thank you so much for your common sense, I'm gonna give it a try right away and keep you posted.

Comment: @buddyshot even linear regulator 7800 serie has 6 mA quiscient current.  You can find with smaller current.